# how can i get the String value of the title from the ListTile which was pressed by the user?

Tags: string, flutter, function, listview

I need the String value of the tapped title from the ListTile

here is my code from the Listviewbuilder:

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            onTap: Ingridients_Selected_x(),
            title: Text(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!),
          )
         )
         )
```

Ingridients*Selected*_x is a function in which I want to give the searched String value

I guess u have to call some argument in the onTap: method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your function with parameters of String title.

```
Ingridients_Selected_x(String title){
  //
}
```

then invoke your function on tap and pass the title value to it.

```
 onTap:(){
      Ingridients_Selected_x(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just accept the String that you want to pass into your function:

```dart
void Ingridients_Selected_x(String ingredientTitle) {
  // ... Your code...
}
```

And in your Listview.builder use an anonymous `() =>` function :

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
      onTap: () => Ingridients_Selected_x(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!),
      title: Text(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Or, to make it simpler, without the anonymous function:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        Ingridients_Selected_x(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!);
      },
      title: Text(displayed_add_ingridients_to_meal[index].Ingridient_title!),
    ),
  ),
)
```